# jquery appendTo not working in IE

Tags: jquery

I have made the following jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xtcZ/13/)

This code works perfectly in firefox, but i cant find out why this wont work in ie anyone care to help me its pretty basic jQuery code

update: well it appears its not the appendTo, if i remove the removeAttr('size') then the code does work so i can live without that in my original setup but would like to know why this causes an error in ie

Comment: You have several `appendTo`s, which one is not working?

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what the outcome should be and what you are seeing.

Comment: If you check this out in firefox you see that each of the input fields has a value set and that they are appended to the corect holder divs

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a guess:

One thing IE never seemed to like is tags without anything in them -- it will often take them out.  I suggest you put a `nbsp;` between every `<div></div>` and `<span></span>` which only has white space content.